# iOS visual flash when altering page length / scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

http://jsbin.com/nesiside/1 (code is available http://jsbin.com/nesiside/1/edit)

If you scroll down in the document and click the "Lock/Unlock" button, an overlay with text will appear. You'll notice that the scrollbar length has been changed to accommodate the overlay height, not the original page height. Click "Unlock" in the overlay, and you return to the original page, in the previous scroll position.

System works great on desktop browsers, and on my Android phone, however, on iOS there is a rendering flash flash when the overlay is triggered or removed. Ultimately, I believe it is the fault of the scrollbar changing.

I've attempted the usual tricks to resolve iOS rendering issues (webkit-backface, transform3d), with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, showing the content and hiding the overlay (or vise versa) was to much for the iPad 4 to render at once, causing the flash. This is odd because I tested it on an old Kindle and my Android phone and both are handled it fine with their slow processors.

To resolve the issue, I put the the scrollTop() method (used to return the user to the previous position on the underlying page) inside a requestAnimationFrame function. The result isn't perfect (content can be screen scrolling for a fraction of as section), but it is a much better result than an entire page flash.